# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Class is not mapped maven multi module project

Tags: java, maven, jpa, persistence, maven-module

Probably if you have an example repository with a project modularized with maven that separates domain and infra it could help me.

I have a project with this modular archtecture:

```
parentProject
  |-domain
  |-infrastructure
  |-app
```

In infrastructure module I have repositories accessing databases. I put in its META-INF the file persistence.xml.
The problem seems to be that Hibernate can't reach NamedQueries in domain module.

**Update 1:**

I added in my persistence file the following line:

```
<jar-file>../domain/target/domain-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</jar-file>
```

And the error ended, however, now I'm getting another error:

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: MyClass is not mapped
I tried to add the line:

```
<class>br.com.leandro.model.MyClass</class>
```

But the error persists.

The first error I got trying to create a named query in **DOMAIN** module, for this
new error, I'm trying to create a native query in the **INFRASTRUCTURE** module.

If any futher information or piece of code is necessary, let me know and I'll be glad to provide it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I have two persistences in the same file and I put `<jar-file>../domain/target/domain-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</jar-file>` only in one of them.